# Position der Angabe "in der Arbeit"

Tags: adverbial

Ich kenne die Position adverbialer Bestimmungen – die Angabe von Informationen zur Art („wie?“), zum Ort („wo?“) und der Zeit („wann?“) – im Satz.
Aber ich bin nicht sicher, wo ich die Information „bei der Arbeit“ in folgendem Satz unterbringen soll (Englisch: “I have a new assignment in my job”):

1. Ich habe eine neue Aufgabe in der Arbeit.
2. Ich habe in der Arbeit eine neue Aufgabe.

Ist es eine Bestimmung des Orts?
Ist *in* dann die richtige Präposition und an welcher Stelle muss die Bestimmung stehen?

Comment: Please provide more context. I am not sure what you are trying to say. It probalby should be "**auf** der Arbeit". And both placements would make sense depending on what you want to empahsize.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i am newbie to write the question in german. Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Das ist eine Bestimmung des Ortes. Die Frage lautet: Wo habe ich eine neue Aufgabe?

Die wohl gängigste Formulierung wäre:

> Ich habe in meiner Arbeit eine neue Aufgabe.

Allerdings ist auch das erste Beispiel in Ordnung, aber weniger gebräuchlich. Die Stellung ist also überaus flexibel.

"in" ist die richtige Präposition, im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch werden aber auch andere Präpositionen benutzt: "bei", "auf". Das ist allerdings nur für das Wort "Arbeit" gültig und kann nicht einfach auf andere Ortsangaben übertragen werden.

Comment: Auch »auf der Arbeit« ist relativ weit verbreitet.

Answer (score 1):

Um das in den Antworten angesprochene Problem der 'richtigen', d.h. regional unterschiedlichen Präposition zu umgehen (auf / bei / in der Arbeit), kannst du ganz einfach sagen:

> Ich habe eine neue Aufgabe **in meinem Job**.

Das ist dann zunächst die Normalstellung, die übliche Reihenfolge, aber wie Thomas gesagt hat: die Reihenfolge ist in diesem Fall flexibel.